# how to show stage name of completed stage and not the tick mark in aura?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-progressindicator, lightning-progressstep

I am using below markup

[image]

```
 <lightning:progressIndicator currentStep="step-4" type='path' variant='non-linear' >
        <lightning:progressStep  label="Step 1" value="step-1" onclick='{!c.termsCondi}'/>
        <lightning:progressStep label="STep 2" value="step-2" onclick='{!c.custDets}'/>
        <lightning:progressStep label="Step 3" value="step-3" onclick='{!c.bankDets}'/>
        
            <lightning:progressStep label="Step 4" value="step-4" onclick='{!c.empDets}'/>
        
        <lightning:progressStep label="Step 5 " value="step-5" onclick='{!c.incomeDets}'/>
    </lightning:progressIndicator>
```

instead of tick mark, I need to get the label shown without hovering over the stage

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the standard component and get that behavior, as it is designed after the [Path](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/path/) element in SLDS. If you want different behavior, you'll have to write your own component. I've actually written a custom path component before (as in, before it was a standard component), so I'll leave you with my [source code](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/2915511e1f1b4186fab25c94254d6899). Please feel free to modify it to meet your needs.